# Lvreduce online on RHEL 6 or centos 6 with ext4 file systems

Tags: lvm, devices, ext4, lvreduce

Is it possible to reduce a mounting lv safely at RHEL6/CentOS6 with ext4 file system? If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per RedHat documentation you can't reduce mounted filesystem. Check [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ext4grow.html) for detailed document